# App crashes when trying to load the data to and from shared preference

Tags: android, notifications, crash

In my app, i am taking the notification posted event and filtering the notification, then saving it in the shared preference from the object model and used hashmap for it :

```
  Map<String,  List<Model>>
```

I am using asynctask to fetch the list back in the app from shared preference :

```
    private class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Map<String,List<Model>>> {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, List<Model>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        SharedPreferences shared;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        shared = getSharedPreferences("MyVariables", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        modelList = gson.fromJson(
                shared.getString("My_map", null),
                new TypeToken<HashMap<String, List<Model>>>() {
                }.getType());
        return modelList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Map<String, List<Model>> stringListMap) {
        super.onPostExecute(stringListMap);
        if(modelList!=null) {
            keys = getKeys(modelList);
            adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), keys);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

The saving of the data is in this function :

```
     private void saveMap(Map<String,List<Model>> inputMap){
    SharedPreferences shared;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    shared = getSharedPreferences("MyVariables", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = shared.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(inputMap);
    editor.putString("My_map", json);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Whenever a new notification is posted , i extract the data from it and save it in the local hashmap and to the shared prefernce too . and at the time of app opening i load the data from the shared preference to the local list .

What i am not able to understand is the reason of anr in my app whenever  a new notification is posted.

```
It has been 8006.8ms since event, 8006.4ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 2.  Wait queue head age: 9112.1ms.

 Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 2.  Wait queue head age: 9112.1ms.
```

Comment: I believe you are doing some task on UI thread which keeps it blocking and hence the ANR.

Answer (score 2):

Good day!
First of all, you should move a call of saveMap() function to background thread. For example inside doInBackground().

Also I recommend you to think about using database to store notifications - there are too complex to be stored in Shared Preferences.

Comment: If i use database then i am stuck at a point , that rows are made based on apps  and for each app there is more than one notification so a list of stings of notification is there .. how do i handle that? like 1 student and 5 subjects .

Comment: @beginner A piece of cake! :) It's a standard task for a database. Concrete way depends on database type (relative [sqlile and Room, for example] or no-sql [for example, Realm]). 
For Room see this article, for example: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a